# Get title from newly opened page puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to get the a new tab and scrape the title of that page with `puppeteer`.

This is what I have

```
// use puppeteer
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//set wait length in ms: 1000ms = 1sec
const short_wait_ms = 1000

async function run() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, timeout: 0});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto('https://biologyforfun.wordpress.com/2017/04/03/interpreting-random-effects-in-linear-mixed-effect-models/');

    // second page DOM elements
    const CLICKHERE_SELECTOR = '#post-2068 > div > div.entry-content > p:nth-child(2) > a:nth-child(1)';

    // main page
    await page.waitFor(short_wait_ms);
    await page.click(CLICKHERE_SELECTOR);


    // new tab opens - move to new tab
    let pages = await browser.pages();

    //go to the newly opened page

    //console.log title -- Generalized Linear Mixed Models in Ecology and in R

}

run();
```

I can't figure out how to use `browser.page()` to start working on the new page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagetitle):

> #### page.title()
>
> - returns: `<`[`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)`<`[`string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#String_type)`>>` Returns page's title.
>
> Shortcut for [`page.mainFrame().title()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#frametitle).

Therefore, you should use `page.title()` for getting the title of the newly opened page.

Alternatively, you can gain a slight performance boost by using the following:

```
page._frameManager._mainFrame.evaluate(() => document.title)
```

> **Note:** Make sure to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) operator when calling `page.title()`, as the title tag must be downloaded before Puppeteer can access its content.

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't need to move to the new tab.

To get the title of any page you can use:

```
const pageTitle = await page.title();
```

Also after you click something and you're waiting for the new page to load you should wait for the load event or the network to be Idle:

```
// Wait for redirection
await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle', networkIdleTimeout: 1000});
```

Check the docs: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions